# How do I keep log messages out of STDOUT when running Rake tasks on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I have some Rake tasks that produce CSV output which I'd like to redirect to a file and open with other tools, but when I run `heroku rake foo > foo.csv` I get log messages (SQL queries, etc.) in my output.

I've tried `Rails.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')` and `Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDERR)` at the top of the Rake task and while those function as expected locally, they don't have any noticeable effect when I run the task on Heroku.

I'm not too shocked that Heroku would squash STDOUT and STDERR together but it's a mystery to me why sending to /dev/null would not kill the output.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Rails v3.0.0, Heroku bamboo-ree-1.8.7 stack, rake 0.9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Heroku | Dev Center | Logging](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging):

> When a Rails app is pushed, we will automatically install the [rails_log_stdout](http://github.com/ddollar/rails_log_stdout) plugin into the application which will redirect logs to `stdout`.

I think Heroku includes (in the output sent through your `git push` command) a notification about this (and one other addition: for serving static/`public` content, if I remember correctly). You may only see the notifications for certain kinds of pushes though (complete slug rebuilds?). I remember seeing it when I recently pushed a new application to a Bamboo/MRI-1.9.2 stack, but I do not think I got the message every time I pushed changes to just the application’s code (maybe adding a new gem to the Gemfile is enough to trigger it?).

---

Several Rails subsystems keep their own `logger` binding (independent bindings whose values are often initialized from `Rails.logger`; reassigning the latter does not change the former):

- [`ActiveRecord::Base.logger`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.9/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L42)
- [`ActionController::Base.logger`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.9/actionpack/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb#L35)
- [`ActionMailer::Base.logger`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.9/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/railtie.rb#L9)

Heroku’s changes probably set a new value for `Rails.logger` before `ActiveRecord` is initialized. When `ActiveRecord` is eventually loaded, it sets its own `logger` to be the same as `Rails.logger` (the Heroku/stdout one). When your task runs, it reassigns `Rails.logger`, but it is too late for this to have any effect on `ActiveRecord::Base.logger` (the only most likely to be handling the SQL logs).

You probably need to reassign some of these other `logger` bindings to squelch the logging going to STDOUT. Some other likely locations are listed in rails_log_stdout’s [`init.rb`](https://github.com/ddollar/rails_log_stdout/blob/master/init.rb) in the Rails 2 section.

Comment: I am aware of this and so I knew the general cause of what's happening, but what's the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, though I didn't run into it until I changed `config/environments/production.rb` to have this:

```
  config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

(I did this so that my app would log to the heroku log.)

My fix was this:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) unless 'rake' == File.basename($0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and found the following to be a more convenient workaround:

Add the following to `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.logger.level = Logger.const_get(ENV['LOG_LEVEL'] ? ENV['LOG_LEVEL'].upcase : 'INFO')
```

Push to Heroku, then when you run your rake tasks add `LOG_LEVEL="fatal"` **to the end** of the command (replace `foo` and `foo.csv` with your things):

```
heroku run rake foo LOG_LEVEL="fatal" > foo.csv
```

I have `log_level` set to `fatal` in the above example, but it can be any of the following: `debug|info|warn|error|fatal`. In our case, using the highest would mean nothing but the most fatal errors are outputted into the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help anyone with a "fresh" Rails project pushing to Heroku:

You need a combination of @Matt Burke and @Hengjie's answer:

Add these two lines to **config/environments/production.rb**:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger.level = Logger.const_get(ENV['LOG_LEVEL'] ? ENV['LOG_LEVEL'].upcase : 'INFO')
```

This will setup a new STDOUT logger and allow you to easily control the log resolution with the LOG_LEVEL environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the following change to production.rb:

```
if 'rake' == File.basename($0)
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new('rake.log', 'daily')
end
```

I suppose we could ignore the output as well

```
if 'rake' == File.basename($0)
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')
end
```